# How I can add rendered comdition on dynamic apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

This is my code. I dont want to display the records which having null Id.
I am adding this value on pageblocktable.

```
        Component.Apex.outputLink link = new Component.Apex.outputLink();
        link.expressions.value='/'+'{!l.Id}';
        link.expressions.title='{!l.Id}';   

        Component.Apex.outputText txt = new Component.Apex.outputText();
        txt.expressions.value='{!l.Id}';
        link.childComponents.add(txt);
        Component.Apex.Column columnLink = new Component.Apex.Column(headerValue='Link');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can always write the expression as below in dynamic vf,

```
link.expressions.render='{!IF(NOT(ISNULL(l.ID)),true,false)}';
```

Or alternately in query filter with l.Id not equal to null.